# C++ Design Pattern library?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, c++11, libraries

What is the most common C++ Design Pattern libraries?

I've read about [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Main.HomePage) library in Alexandrescu's book, but looks like it somewhat dead now. Is there something similar out there?

Comment: See [this presentation](http://accu.org/content/conf2013/Tobias_Darm_Effective_GoF_Patterns.pdf) for a a modern C++11 approach to GoF design patterns

Comment: I've reworded the question, may be we will reopen it?

Comment: Mmm? `Loki` library's dead?

Comment: @AdriC.S. At least latest release was on January 2009.

Comment: It's not that "loki is dead". The fact is that many things Loki implements are now (under different approach) part of C++11. Out of them remains very few.

Comment: @TemplateRex: your comment deserves to be an answer!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> “Design patterns are bug reports against your programming language” --
>   Peter Norvig

To answer the question why there are not many C++ design pattern libraries, it is useful to know what design patterns were meant to solve in the first place. The classic GoF book states in the preface

> Design patterns describe simple and elegant solutions to specific
>   problems in object-oriented software design.

The 90s style of object-oriented programming relied heavily on using abstract classes as interfaces, with concrete implementation classes deriving from these interfaces. The GoF patterns describe creational, structural and behavioral relationships between objects of different class types. They key element was: **encapsulate and parameterize whatever will frequently change**. Many of the GoF patterns can also be reformulated using templates, but then the flexibility is constrained to compile-time rather than run-time.

Object-oriented programming makes it very easy to add different concrete implementations of an interface. What OOP has a hard time with is adding new functionality to existing interfaces. The [**Visitor pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is the prime example: it is essentially a work-around that relies on an extra level of indirection to allow new algorithms to work on existing data structures.

This is the exact opposite of functional programming: with functional programming it is very easy to add new functions for existing data, but it is much harder to add new data types to which such functions apply. The difficulty in getting extensibility in both functions and types is called the **[expression problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem)**.

OOP style polymorphism is heavily based on **internal polymorphism**: the dynamic function dispatch is based on the object's type. Modern C++ also uses **external polymorphism** where techniques such as **type erasure** allow run-time flexibility with a static interface. The new `std::shared_ptr` and `boost::any` or `adobe::poly` classes are prime example of these techniques.

A recent [ACCU presentation by Tobias Darm](http://accu.org/content/conf2013/Tobias_Darm_Effective_GoF_Patterns.pdf) showed many examples of transforming the old internally polymporhic GoF patterns to this new style externally polymorphic patterns. The rough idea is to replace abstract classes with a function argument that can take `std::function` as a parameter. The `std::function` then controls the polymorphic flexibility from the outside. Many of the GoF patterns can be greatly enhanced in terms of boilerplate this way.

**TL;DR**: The classic GoF patterns were tailored to solve OOP shortcomings. But OOP is no longer the dominant C++ style. A combination of generic programming (the Standard Library, Boost) and OOP can solve many problems more elegantly, making classic design patterns no longer the go-to solution.

Comment: The idea provided by Tobias Darm is very promising. Are there any changes to see the video too?

Comment: @cody I haven't been able to locate the video. Not sure whether all ACCU sessions were filmed.

Comment: I've found the video: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/gof-patterns-c-plus-plus-boost

Answer (score 17):

The original definition of a design pattern was a reusable *approach* to a reoccurring problem that could **not** be conveniently encapsulated in a library. Thus, the moment you *can* encapsulate a pattern in a library, it ceases to be a pattern, in my opinion. This has, for instance, largely happened with iterators in C++, as the standard C++ library has a comprehensive framework for implementing iterators now.

I’ve never tried to use Loki, but reading Alexandrescu’s book, I was not persuaded that a library based approach really had much to offer for many patterns.

Comment: Well it is a matter of convenience. I often use my hand-made implementations of Observer and Singleton. But I'd prefer to use something widely used instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: But you’re **not** “reinventing the wheel”. The pattern IS the wheel, and if you’re following its design and terminology, you *are* using what is “widely used”; more so, in fact, than if you’re coding to the potentially idiosyncratic conventions of a “patterns library” (Again, there are exceptions, like iterators in modern C++, where the library conventions are far more widely used than the GoF pattern).

Comment: "as the standard C++ library has a comprehensive framework for implementing iterators now" Would you mind elaborating on that? I know there are iterator traits (and the related `iterator` base class), but I'm not aware of a *comprehensive framework for implementing iterators* in the Standard Library.

Comment: @DyP, I may have been guilty of a bit of hyperbole… I was indeed thinking of `std::iterator_traits` and `std::iterator`, but also of the consumer infrastructure, i.e. an iterator written to standard library conventions also can be plugged into all standard library algorithms defined for its category.

Answer (score 3):

May seems tautology, but the most common is ... the standard library itself!

It is not -strictly speaking- a "pattern library", but a folder for a number of tools addressing common pattern implementation.

Note that your question is not answerable, being a pattern just a conceptual definition commonly used in a variety of problems. Libraries don't provide patterns, they (can) use patterns (like anybody else can) to provide implementation of specific problem solutions.

Patterns are at an higher abstraction layer than coding.

Comment: So you think such patterns as Singleton, Observer, Visitor, may be Abstract Factory can't be implemented in a header via templates? I know at least one library which do this: Loki.

Comment: Loki is not a pattern implementation. Is a library that uses those patterns to provide tools to do other things. Defining classes is programming objects. Defining templates is programming classes. Defining concepts is programming templates. Defining pattern is programming concepts. The fact the loki uses same names doesn't make it a "pattern": it sits on a different abstraction layer.

Comment: Well I see what you mean. You are talking about strict definition of design patterns. In fact I don't need that. I need a header with template class Observable (for example), I will inherit that class, and I'll be able to use some methods like AddObserver and NotifyObservers, thus I will use pattern Observer. Now I'm clear?

Comment: @Cody: yes, perfectly. The point is that the way you implement an "observable" depends on the way you want to "observe". If you use a given implementation you are forced to folloow a "coupling mechanism" in a way that may not be what you need for your purpose. Seriusly: give a look to [http://accu.org/content/conf2013/Tobias_Darm_Effective_GoF_Patterns.pdf] : You will find that many patterns are just into the standard library. You just only have to know about it.

Comment: There is an extra ']' in your link, so it is broken. But I'm reading that presentation right now. It would be nice to watch the video too, but I can't find a link for now.

Comment: Fixing the link: https://accu.org/content/conf2013/Tobias_Darm_Effective_GoF_Patterns.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to improve code **maintainability**, **re-usability** and **readability**, some researchers (such as GoF, Booch) started examining best practices. They have noticed that there are some patterns adopted by experienced developers to address specific design problems.

As you can see, **experience** created design patterns. So using design patterns is coding like a specialist. And there is no silver bullet for this.

It is true that some straightforward design patterns such as decorators find support from specific languages. But that's the limit. Domain specific frameworks also guide you to use their interfaces to complete the design pattern decided by the authors of those.

Libraries will only help you understand how design patterns used in that library will facilitate your implementation. It won't even give you a choice to change the design.